# Showing a line above navigationbar

Tags: android, navigationbar

I want to show a line above navigation bar, like this :

[image: Desired result]
I know I can edit the layout xml to do it, but that will modify a lot of  files. Is there an easier way？

Comment: I think you can only add that through the *layout* itself by adding *Horizontal View* at *alignParentBottom* !.

Comment: This way must modify every activity layout xml . I want to know whether has a global way to modify this.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying layout file is an easier way indeed. As I know,there isn't an attribute for achieving this only one line code.

You could create a [layer list](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#LayerList) resource and set it as the background of navigation view.

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimaryDark" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:top="1dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply ！I don't how to get the navigation view and set its background drawable .

Comment: @lazyape could you post layout xml file

Comment: Sorry , maybe I didn't make myself clear. The navigation bar is a system ui , not in my layout xml .

Comment: @lazyape my misunderstanding, let's find other solution

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do it is add a line in your layout xml file and constraint it to the bottom of the layout.

> a normal constraint layout with a line, a line can be any type of view (TextView, Button,...)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1"
    />
```

> a normal relative layout with aline

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottom_line"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="3dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1" />
```

Comment: Thanks ! My English is not very good, may not express clearly . The navigation bar is a system ui .  If I modify layout xml , I must modify every activity layout .